# How to replace all dollar signs before all variables inside a double-quoted string with sed?

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed

I have problems replacing the variables that are inside strings in bash. For example, I want to replace

```
"test$FOO1=$FOO2" $BAR
```

with:

```
"test" .. FOO1 .. "=" .. FOO2 .. "" $BAR
```

I tried:

```
sed 's/\$\([A-Z0-9_]\+\)\b/" .. \1 .. "/g'
```

But I don't want to replace variables the same way outside of double-quoted strings, e.g. like:

```
if [ $VARIABLE = 1 ]; then
```

Has to be replaced by just

```
if VARIABLE then
```

Is there a way to replace only **inside** of double-quotes?

Background:
I want to [convert a bash script into Lua script](https://github.com/rubo77/Bash2Lua-transpiler/blob/master/bash2lua.sh).

I am aware, that it will not be easily possible to convert all possible shell scripts this way, but what I want to achieve is to replace all basic language constructs with Lua commands and replace all variables and conditionals. An automation here will save much work when translating bash into Lua by hand

Comment: `[ $VARIABLE = 1 ]` is a bug anyway; it *should* be `[ "$VARIABLE" = 1 ]`. You can't just go by what is quoted and what isn't. Effectively translating between two languages means parsing the source to build an abstract syntax tree, then using that tree to generate code in the target language.

Comment: For example, what would you do with something like  `if [ "$FOO -- $BAR" = "hello -- there -- world" ];`?

Comment: Sure, it will not be perfect, but with the right preparation of the bash source, you can achieve a lot in automatic translating to Lua and save a lot of manual work

Comment: `[ $VARIABLE = 1 ]` does not always need quotes around: depending on the source of VARIABLE

Comment: maybe this project will have helpful ideas on your overall goal, rather than this specific issue:  https://github.com/3scale/apicast-cli/issues/1

Comment: The original example went from a balanced pair of double quotes to two or more balanced double quotes. The amended example now goes from balanced double quotes to an unbalanced double quotes. Is this intended?

Comment: Sorry, I was not absolute clear in the first example. I want to convert **a whole bash script with simple bash** into Lua script, so this is how it must work. I added the missing `"` before the last variable in the example

Answer (score 0):

This with GNU awk for multi-char RS, RT, and gensub() shows one way to separate and then manipulate quoted (in RT) and unquoted (in $0) strings as a starting point:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="\"[^\"]*\""; ORS="" }
{
    $0 = gensub(/\[\s+[$]([[:alnum:]_]+)\s+=\s+\S+\s+];/,"\\1","g",$0)
    RT = gensub(/[$]([[:alnum:]_]+)"/,"\" .. \\1","g",RT)
    RT = gensub(/[$]([[:alnum:]_]+)/,"\" .. \\1 .. \"","g",RT)
    print $0 RT
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"count: " .. FOO .. " times " .. BAR
if VARIABLE then
```

The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat file
"count: $FOO times $BAR"
if [ $VARIABLE = 1 ]; then
```

NOTE: this approach of matching strings with regexps will always just be a best effort based on the samples provided, you'd need a shell language parser to do the job robustly.

Comment: This works fine, How can I add this in a row with other commands in my script at https://github.com/rubo77/Bash2Lua-transpiler/blob/master/bash2lua.sh ?
And maybe you can add an explanation about this confusing RS and RT, where it comes from?

Comment: I found out: just pipe it into awk like: `| awk 'BEGIN { RS=...' `

Comment: Did you try [googling gawk RS RT](https://www.google.com/search?q=gawk+RS+RT)? The gawk manual entires that produces will explain those constructs much better than I can. wrt `How can I...` - ask a new question with its own [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

#### bash lexer for shell!?

I'm so sorry: I just post this answer to warn you about a wrong way!

Reading *language* is a job for a consistant *lexer* not for *sed* nor any *regex* based tool!!!

See [GNU Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), [Berkeley Yacc (byacc)](https://invisible-island.net/byacc/).

You could have a look at [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s sources in order to see how scripts are read!

Persisting in this way will bring you quickly to big script, then further to unsolvable problems.

Answer (score 0):

using group and recursive

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's/^\(\([^"]*\("[^"]*"\)*\)*\)\("[^$"]*\)[$]\([A-Z0-9_]\{1,\}\)/\1\4 .. \5 .. /;t a'
```

1. isolate in string from previous part with
   `^\(\([^"]*\("[^"]*"\)*\)*\)` in group 1
2. select the var content in the string isolated with `s\("[^$"]*\)[$]\([A-Z0-9_]\{1,\}\)'` in group 4 (prefix) and 5 (var name)
3. change like you want  with `\1\4 .. \5 ..`
4. repeat this operation while a change is occuring `:a` and `t a`

with a gnu sed you can reduce the command to (no `-e` needed to target the label a):

```
sed ':a;s/^\(\([^"]*\("[^"]*"\)*\)*\)\("[^$"]*\)[$]\([A-Z0-9_]\{1,\}\)/\1\4 .. \5 .. /;t a'
```

Assuming there is no quote (escaped one) in string. If so a first pass is needed to change them and put them back after main modification.

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^"$]*"[^"]*)*"[^"$]*)\$([^" ]*) /\1" .. \3  .. " /;ta;s/^([^"]*("[^"$]*"[^"]*)*"[^"$]*)\$([^"]*)"/\1" .. \3/;ta' file
```

When changing things within double quotes, first we must sail passed any double quoted strings that do **not** need changing. This means anchoring the regexp to the start of the line using the `^` metacharacter and iterating the regexp until all cases cease to exist.

First, eliminate zero or more characters which are not double quotes from the start of the line.

Second, eliminate double quoted strings which do not contain the character of interest (TCOI) i.e. `$`, followed by  zero or more characters which are not double quotes, zero or more times.

Third, eliminate double quotes followed by zero or more characters which are not double quotes or TCOI i.e. `$`.

The following character (if it exists) must be TCOI. Group the entire collection of strings before in a back reference `\1`.

Following TCOI, one or more conditions may be grouped. In the above example the first condition is when a variable (beginning with TCOI) is followed by a space. The second condition is when the variable is followed directly by `"`. Hence this entails two substitution commands, the `ta` command, branches to the loop identified `a` when the substitution was successful.

N.B. The `if [ $VARIABLE = 1 ]; then` situation can be treated in the same vien, here the `[` is the opening double quote and the `]` is the closing double quote.

P.S. TCOI was `$` and this is also a metacharacter in regexp that represents the end of a line, it therefore must be quoted e.g.`\$`

P.P.S. Don't forget to quote the `[`'s and `]`'s too. If quotings not your thing, then enclose the character in `[x]` where x is the character to be quoted.

EDIT:

```
sed -E ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^"$]*"[^"]*)*"[^"$]*)\$([[:alnum:]]*)/\1" .. \3  .. "/;ta' file
```

Since the original example has been replace by the OP here is a solution based on the new example.